# Renaming duplicating values in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel database with the following structure:

- **Unique groups**: each may have several entries but their numbers are unique
- **Subgroups**: may have the same numbers within groups but never between the groups

  I need to rename those subgroups that are repeated between different groups.

[image]

I could use nested IF formula, but the number of entries in groups and subgroups may differ a lot. So far I haven't managed to construct a working nested loop.

Comment: Creating a dictionary whose keys are subgroups (the second column) and whose values are e.g. arrays of groups (drawn from the first column) seems like a natural place to start.

Comment: Why subgroup `97` is not splited into `97-1` and `97-1` (see rows: 4 and 5)?

Comment: Are the numbers in the first column always like in your example? Nondecreasing and consisting of consecutive numbers? If so, there is an easy solution for your problem, one that doesn't involve nested loops (which would make the run-time quadratic) and doesn't require dictionaries.

Comment: @MaciejLos The subgroup `97` entries (rows 4 and 5) belong to the same group `3`, thus their repetition is within the group and it is ok.

Comment: @JohnColeman The group ids in column 1 are more complicated than in this example, they are strings, i.e. may even contain letters.

Comment: You mean, if it's a first occurance, a subgroup id + an extra `-1` is not obligatory?

Comment: @MaciejLos Exactly. But if there was `4` instead of `3` in `A5` then both `97` should be renamed as `97-1` and `97-2`.

Comment: What have you tried? This just seems like a request  for code?

Comment: You can avoid VBA using a proper array-formula: see the solution I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a NOT-VBA solution with a nested IF *array formula*:

1. in cell C2 type

   ```
   =CONCATENATE(
                IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$12,CONCATENATE("<>",A2),B$2:B$12,B2)=0,
                   B2,
                   IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A$2,A2,B1:B$2,B2)=0,
                      B2 & "-" & IF(COUNTIF(B1:B$2,B2)=0,
                                    1,
                                    RIGHT(OFFSET(B$1,LARGE(IF(B1:B$2=B2,ROW(B1:B$2),""),1)-1,1),
                                          LEN(OFFSET(B$1,LARGE(IF(B1:B$2=B2,ROW(B1:B$2),""),1)-1,1)) -
                                          FIND("-",OFFSET(B$1,LARGE(IF(B1:B$2=B2,ROW(B1:B$2),""),1)-1,1))
                                          )+1
                                   ),
                      OFFSET(B$1,LARGE(IF(B1:B$2=B2,IF(A1:A$2=A2,ROW(B1:B$2),""),""),1)-1,1))
                  )
               )
   ```
2. press CTRL-ALT-Return to input it as an *array-formula*
3. copy the formula in C2 and paste it form C3 downwards

Comment: Thank you! I never heard of array formulas, so will try this as well.

Comment: I am sorry but my Excel (2003) complains that there is an error in the formula, and I failed to find the reason. It highlights the first ROW function but can't see what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dictionary-based approach that you should be able to tweak:

```
Sub LabelSubgroups(R As Range)
    'R is assumed to be a 3-column range
    'Consisting of the data without the header as well as the
    'final column to contain the results
    'Note that the final column will be overwritten

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim key1 As Variant, key2 As Variant
    Dim D As Object, Grp As Object
    Dim A As Variant

    n = R.Rows.Count
    A = R.Value
    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 1 To n
        key1 = A(i, 2)
        key2 = A(i, 1)
        If D.Exists(key1) Then
            If Not D(key1).Exists(key2) Then
                D(key1).Add key2, D(key1).Count + 1
            End If
        Else
            Set Grp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            Grp.Add key2, 1
            D.Add key1, Grp
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To n
        key1 = A(i, 2)
        If D(key1).Count > 1 Then
            key2 = A(i, 1)
            A(i, 3) = key1 & "-" & D(key1)(key2)
        Else
            A(i, 3) = key1
        End If
    Next i

    R.Value = A
End Sub
```

If you run `LabelSubgroups Range("A2:C12")` on your sample data then it produces the desired output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try that with my data!

Comment: I am sorry for taking more of your time, but I have this problem:
How should I run this macro with these arguments?
When I create another sub above it, like:

`Sub CallingLabel()
    
    Call LabelSubgroups("A2:C12")
    
End Sub`

It doesn't work because of syntax.

Comment: @vitar Replace the line which starts `Call` by just `LabelSubgroups Range("A2:C12")`. 1) you need to pass the sub a range rather than a string 2) `Call` is legacy cruft -- no reason to use it, 3) when calling a sub rather than a function (or when calling a function as a sub -- without trying to capture the output), you don't put parentheses around the parameters.

Comment: Thanks, managed to run it! Now trying to debug. It stops at `A(i, 3) = key1` where `i=1` The message from debugger reads `<subscript out of range>`

Comment: It works! Thanks a ton! Will try now with my real data...

Comment: Works with the real data as well! This saves me a few weeks weeks of dull manual work. Thank you very much for your help!